# Inserting Error Oracle

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle

I've been trying to insert to Oracle Table using this script :

```
        Try
            conn.Close()
            conn.Open()
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO PERSONAL(KODEPERSON) VALUES(:KODE)"
            cmd.Parameters.Add(":KODE", "AN001")
            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("SUCESS")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try
```

But when I executed this in VB.NET  It raises error ORA-01036 in EXECUTENONQUERY

Can someone tell me what's going on ?

Thank you everyone, I've been struggling about 1 hour and now I got the solution, please be informed that if we declared the Oracle Command as a public when we used it already in any statements please note that we've to dispose it so it will be no longer left the previous statement cache. God bless everyone

Comment: Which provider are you using?

Comment: Oracle, Visual Basic, Oracle Data Access

Comment: You mean `ODP.NET`? Which class are you using to create the `conn` and `cmd`?

Comment: I mean you're correct I'm using the ODP.NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing
cmd.Parameters.Add(":KODE", "AN001")
to
cmd.Parameters.Add("KODE", "AN001")

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Microsoft's `OracleClient`, you don't need a use a colon in `Parameters.Add`:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("KODE", "AN001")
```

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebxy9a8b.aspx):

> For `Oracle`, when using named parameters in an `SQL` statement or stored procedure, you must precede the parameter name with a colon (`:`). However, when referring to a named parameter elsewhere in your code (for example, when calling `Add`), do not precede the named parameter with a colon (`:`). The `.NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle` supplies the colon automatically.

**Update:**

Use

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("KODE", "AN001")
```

Comment: I still having the same problem, I don't know why this happening. It occurs Illegals Number, Have you tried the code instead?

Comment: I think the solution was OK but I have to admit I got mistaken about this , I will post soon about the progress